# Debian Wheezy live - gparted, dmsg, fdisk etc. do not detect local hard drive but it is shown during installation

Tags: debian, hard-disk, fdisk, gparted

Yesterday I finished backing up my data and it was time to wipe that HDD of mine for good and freshly install Debian Wheezy stable with **Xfce** as a WM. I've booted into a live session to see if things like sound, wireless etc. work and they did without a problem. However I was surprised that after I installed gparted (again: live session) I was facing a single partition with approx 7.5GB (the size of my USB key). Okay, it automatically shows the device where the OS is booted from. However when I looked at the drop-down menu (top right) for selecting a device I saw that only **/dev/sda1 (7.48GB)** was available. No local hard drive at all. I opened the terminal and did

```
dmsg | less
```

after that

```
df -h
```

and finally

```
sudo  fdisk -l
```

but all was in vain. The only thing that I'm looking at was my USB key and that's all.

Then I decided to see how the installation goes and if the same issue occurs. For my (delightful) surprise when I got to the *Detecting hardware* and then to the *Partition hard disks* part there it was - almost 500GB of space. The only thing that's bothering me is the amount of time the formatting takes. Is it normal for a 3 hours of formatting to do only 13% of the 500GB? I remember clearly when I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS years ago that it took much less even though back then I also had a dual boot with Win7 and multiple other partitions so the formated space was like 200GB. That's the reason why I wanted to use gparted in a live session in the first place because gparted is usually pretty fast when wiping stuff and at least that I could do in order to boost the installation process of my Debian.

Any ideas why gparted, fdisk etc. are not showing my hard disk? I also clearly remember that back then when I installed Ubuntu I also checked the situation with gparted. Even though it was again a live session, everything showed as expected - both USB key and HDD.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour does sound unusual and might be an indication of a hardware problem.  The problem might be as simple as a loose cable, or could be a failing hard drive.

You might consider looking at the drive statistics using a tool such as [gsmartcontrol](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/).  Note that you will need to run the application as root so that it has full access to the hard drive.

Comment: SMART shows full health and the couple of benchmarks I did were also successful. Anyways the installation went without a single problem. However this is still an unresolved issue.